# Remove Letters and special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to remove the letters and special characters from javascript.

Example:

```
var id = "Parameter[0].Category"
```

I only need the "0" from this. Thank you

Comment: Please show some effort. There should be plenty resources available to start and try to code this yourself. If you still have trouble to find a solution, show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out letters and special characters you can use regular expression in JS, like this:

```
id = id.replace(/\D/g, "")
```

You replace every (`g` option) character in your string that is not a digit `\D` with blank `""`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var numbers = id.match(/\d+/)[0];
console.log(numbers);
```

In general this is called filtering using regular expressions.